# Using 3.3v for ICSP programmer

Tags: atmega, atmega328p

I have a circuit that is connected to a VCC of 3.3v because there is a component connect that only runs on 3.3v.

Also a Atmega328p is connected to this VCC and now I am trying to add an ICSP. But all programmers will use 5v to program, which could potentially break my 3.3v IC.

Does a programmer not supply voltage if it sees there is already a voltage present? Or should I just not connect the 5v line of the ICSP header and make sure it's 3.3v powered when programming?

Answer (score 2):

Some programmers supply power to the target device, some do not, and some have a switch or jumper to select it. This varies on a programmer-by-programmer basis and you will have to examine the documentation and/or schematic of the programmer to verify.

Additionally, you *must not* apply 5V to any pin of a 3.3V device unless it is strongly current-limited in order to avoid burning out the pin's protection diodes.

And furthermore, not all AVRs actually support programming at 3.3V, so read the "Memory Programming" section, "Serial Programming" subsection of the datasheet for the device before attempting to do so.

Comment: I didn't consider the lower programming voltage, but it seems it's good for the AVR: "To allow programming of targets running at any allowed voltage (2.7 - 6.0 V)...".

Comment: I have a few random programmers without jumpers and a USBASP with a jumper. But to be safe, could I not just never connect the VCC for the programmer pin? It wouldn't make any difference I suppose.

Comment: @Rogier21: The programmer will attempt to drive its outputs up to its full supply level, so you must limit the current (to 2mA or less) on any signal from the programmer. Fortunately a 5V device has a 3V high threshold so you will most likely not need any translation on signals going *to* the programmer.